# Print to local computer from my POS web app hosted online

Tags: php

I have this pos web app which i want to run on Online.It prints kot,bar and invoices after the order is made by the client.

I have followed many old/dead/useless links and have not found any up-to-date solutions to this although many tantalising glimmers of hope.

The scenario is : Remote hosted website web app generates invoices which is sent to a specified printers on the user pc bar,kitchen etc at the same time (not the default printer) silently (no extra clicking through of print prompts).

I have created a script that runs a command that detects all the currently available printers on the **local** **pc** and then the users choose them to specify them to specific printer to send to.The problem is that this code detects the printers on the current local server.So, when the app is hosted on an online server my whole script becomes useless.

So, is there any way to  detect the printers currently available on the local machine on which the web app is opened from.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The PHP program is running on the server. It is not running on the same computer as the browser.

(Unless the browser is requesting the site from localhost, which it isn't in this case).

Comment: how about i detect the local printers with javascript?

Comment: Browsers do not provide any APIs that expose that information to JS.